# why do my questions always get a lower number of views?

Tags: discussion

I always find that my questions get very less number of views and so i am unable to get satisfactory answers. Is there any reason behind it? Are there any tricks that can be used to get more views?

Comment: Ask a good question and the views will come. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx